# Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, html, nullpointerexception, dom-events

My Javascript doesn't load saying that in line 9 of my javascript `if (panel.style.maxHeight)` "Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLButtonElement."

This is my HTML:

```
<p><button class="accordion">Section 1</button></p>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<p><button class="accordion">Section 2</button></p>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<p><button class="accordion">Section 3</button></p>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

This is my corresponding JavaScript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that `this.nextElementSibling` returns an element?

Comment: what do you expect there is no next sibling, remove your p

Comment: `nextElementSibling` would return something at the same tree level as the button, and there is nothing else at the same level. [Shoot, posted seconds too late. What Eugen said.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a check to see if the panel sibling exists and put the accordion on the same level as the panel.

Removed the paragraph wrapper around the button to demonstrate the functionality

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (!panel) return;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<p><button class="accordion">Section 2</button></p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<p><button class="accordion">Section 3</button></p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```